# HTML Positioning text between 2 lines in Table cell

Tags: html

I'm beginner in HTML. I have 2 lines of text (used 
 to make it in next line) in  and i need to add a line at the right side of those 2 lines, but it needs to be positioned between those, but on the right side of these lines. Something like:
1st line
Additional text
2nd line

But there cannot be  hard space between lines.
Any ideas?

I tried aligining text and styling.

Comment: Can you share your code? so that others can figure out the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.